# How do I add a fixed-row-format import type to uRapidFlowPro?

Tags: magento2, module

I want to add a new type of Fixed Row Format import to uRapidFlow Pro (Magento 2.x) - however the code is completely obfuscated.

Is there a way to do this, and what would I need to do in order to plugin to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a question to Unirgy Support about this, and Petar was incredibly helpful with pointing me at where to start with it.  I also had some great help from the MageSlack community in piecing together some other information.

First you need to create a `urapidflow.xml` file in your module.  This file is responsible for telling uRapidFlow about what data types and row types are available.  This file isn't obfuscated, so you can see examples in the uRapidFlow Pro module.

There are two attack vectors here - you can create your own import type, or overwrite and extend an existing one (like "Products Extra").  I created my own - as I felt this was the best vector for stability and future updates.

My file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <urapidflow>
        <data_types>
            <nameproduct_extra>
                <title>Name Products Extra</title>
                <row_format>fixed</row_format>
                <model>MemorialBracelets\NameProduct\Model\RapidFlowPro\NameProduct</model>
                <profile>
                    <import>
                        <tabs>
                            <file>
                                <title>File Options</title>
                                <block>Unirgy\RapidFlow\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Edit\Tab\File</block>
                            </file>
                            <csv>
                                <title>Format Options</title>
                                <block>Unirgy\RapidFlow\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Edit\Tab\Csv</block>
                            </csv>
                            <options>
                                <title>Import Options</title>
                                <block>Unirgy\RapidFlowPro\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\ProductExtra\ImportOptions</block>
                            </options>
                            <upload>
                                <title>Upload Files</title>
                                <block>Unirgy\RapidFlow\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Edit\Tab\Upload</block>
                            </upload>
                            <reindex>
                                <title>Reindex</title>
                                <block>Unirgy\RapidFlow\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Edit\Tab\Reindex</block>
                            </reindex>
                        </tabs>
                    </import>
                    <export>
                        <tabs>
                            <file>
                                <title>File Options</title>
                                <block>Unirgy\RapidFlow\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Edit\Tab\File</block>
                            </file>
                            <csv>
                                <title>Format Options</title>
                                <block>Unirgy\RapidFlow\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Edit\Tab\Csv</block>
                            </csv>
                            <options>
                                <title>Export Options</title>
                                <block>Unirgy\RapidFlowPro\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\ProductExtra\ExportOptions</block>
                            </options>
                            <conditions>
                                <title>Export Conditions</title>
                                <block>Unirgy\RapidFlow\Block\Adminhtml\Profile\Edit\Tab\Export\Condition</block>
                            </conditions>
                        </tabs>
                    </export>
                </profile>
            </nameproduct_extra>
        </data_types>

        <row_types>
            <CPNO>
                <title>Catalog Product Name Product Option</title>
                <data_type>nameproduct_extra</data_type>
                <columns>
                    <sku><col>1</col><key>1</key></sku>
                    <linked_sku><col>2</col><key>1</key></linked_sku>
                    <position><col>3</col></position>
                </columns>
            </CPNO>
        </row_types>
    </urapidflow>
</config>
```

`data_types` here is merged to create the varying import types (Products, Products Extra, Categories, etc.).  As previously stated - I created my own "Name Products Extra".  You can see this specified in the `<title>` tag.  The containing tag `<nameproduct_extra>` acts as a unique identifier for this import type.

For `<row_format>` you want `fixed`.  This specifies that it's a [FRF import](http://www.unirgy.com/wiki/urapidflow/fixed_row_format).  FRF is great for supplementary import types - such as linking products together in some fashion.

`model` will be the class responsible for handling the import and export.  It needs to extend from `\Unirgy\RapidFlowPro\Model\ResourceModel\ProductExtra`.

`profile` is how you specify the profile options.  I simply duplicated Unirgy's profile tag - which might actually be disadvantageous as I'm not sure my import supports any of those features (whoops!)

Once you have your datatype you need to create your rowtype.  You do this by adding a `<row_types>` tag (that will be merged), and then you create a tag for your row type.  For me, that's `CPNO`.  This will be the FRF identifier - so you need to make sure it's unique and makes some sense.

Here we have `<title>` which is self-explanatory, we have `<data_type>` which uses an import type's unique identifier to tie this FRF type to that import (so we will use "nameproduct_extra"), and we have `<columns>` which defines what the columns are and what their order should be.

For our simple import, we have `<sku>`, `<linked_sku>`, and `<position>`.

These tags give the column a name, but otherwise aren't used. (They won't be the keys in the array used for import).  These tags have two children:

`<col>` which specifies the position of the column (starting at 1)

`<key>` which specifies whether or not the column is required (`<key>1</key>` indicates it is required.  Failure to include the tag indicates it is not).

That's it for your XML and now you can create your import file.

For your model file, I recommend adding this to the class's PHP DOC.  It will be helpful with your IDE and provide you some auto-complete features for some of the properties and functions that exist (but that you can'd know due to the encoding).

```
/*
 * @method string _getIdBySku(string $sku)
 * @method string _t(string $table)
 *
 * @property AdapterInterface $_read
 * @property AdapterInterface $_write
 *
 * @property Select           $_select
 * @property LoggerInterface  $_logger
 * @property Profile          $_profile
 *
 * @property array            $_rowTypeFields
 * @property array            $_skus (SKU => ID)
 */
```

Of note here is that you have `$_read` and `$_write` adapters (holdovers from Magento 1.x - I believe both point to the same `AdapterInterface` in Magento 2.x), you have `$_select` - which is for your export, and you have `$_logger` and `$_profile`.

You also get some helper functions: `_getIdBySku(string $sku)` returns the product's entity_id given it's sku (and uRapidFlow Pro caches this information), and `_t(string $tableName)` returns the name of a table given it's name (to deal with prefixes and the like).

In this class you do need to create a property `$_dataType` which should point to the same identifier used in your XML file (for me that's `nameproduct_extra`).

Then, you need to create a couple functions responsible for handling the import/export.  All of these functions end in your FRF identifier (which for me is CPNO) so replace that in your own implementation:

- `_exportInitCPNO() : void` - creates the select statement for the export
- `_deleteRowCPNO(array $row) : int` - Deletes a row for an FRF import line starting with `-`
- `_importRowCPNO)(array $row) : int` - Imports a row for an FRF import line (may start with + but is optional)

In `_exportInit` you need to create the Select statement for the export and assign it to `$this->_select`.  Alias your database columns to the columns specified in your XML file (sku, linked_sku, and position), and **be sure to alias your table to "`main`"** (otherwise the entire thing will fail).

In `_deleteRow` you receive a 0-based numeric array containing the fields.  `$row[0]` should be your negative identifier (for me `-CPNO`), and then the rest are your columns (`$row[1]` being sku, etc.)

In `_importRow` you receive the same type of array - no reason to say the exact same thing.

For these last two, you should also return the status of the command.

To report that there was no change: `return self::IMPORT_ROW_RESULT_NOCHANGE`.

The report that it was successful: `return self::IMPORT_ROW_RESULT_SUCCESS`.

In addition to that, you may want to output a warning:

```
$this->_profile->getLogger()->setColumn($col); // Optional: assign the coming message a column - 0 if not called (use 0 for the entire row)
$this->_profile->addValue('num_warnings'); // increment the warning counter by 1
$this->_profile->getLogger()->warning($message); // add the warning message
```

Or an error:

```
// setColumn works here too!
$this->_profile->addValue('num_errors');
$this->_profile->getLogger()->error($message);
```

Or maybe you want to attach a message to the success:

```
// setColumn works here also!
$this->_profile->getLogger()->success($message);
```

And that's all there is to it!

[I go into slightly more detail on my blog post about it](http://blog.briteskies.com/blog/extending-urapidflow-with-a-new-profile-type-in-magento-2), but this should serve as a good summary.